# Webservice is hiding original class names

Tags: asp.net, web-services, strongly-typed-dataset

I have a DataLayer project with typed dataset.

I have another project called SiteWebServices which contains only webservices.

I have another web application project which is normal website. This uses SiteWebServices which uses DataLayer.

Now SiteWebServices project hides the original DataLayer classes with its own namespace. For eg; DataLayer.SiteDS.COMPLAINTDataTable is exposed as SiteWebServices.SiteDS.COMPLAINTDataTable.

Everything is working fine, except that data is recevied fine in the webmethod, but when consuming it in the website, nothing is received. No error is generated anywhere.

I have uploaded the code here at my website (safe) [Source code](http://www.tracknifty.com/webappsl.rar).
There are 2 webservices, and 2 corresponding test pages in respective projects, with proper comments in 2 webmethods.

Answer (score 0):

Need more explaination, you should better test webservices standalone with SOAPUI (http://www.soapui.org/)